# convert one element to int in a multiple assignment

Tags: python

Having the following code :

```
queue_name, tasks_to_lease = self.configuration_service.get_value('tags')[self.task_tag].split('=')
tasks_to_lease = int(tasks_to_lease)
```

Any way to do that in one single line ?

Comment: For what purpose? Why does it matter?

Comment: tasks_to_lease = int(self.configuration_service.get_value('tags')[self.task_tag].split('=')[1]) should do it, although it's neither much shorter nor prettier.

Comment: queue_name, tasks_to_lease = self.configuration_service.get_value('tags')[self.task_tag].split('=')[0],int(self.configuration_service.get_value('tags')[self.task_tag].split('=')[1])

Comment: One-liners are better if they are more clear.  But usually they're less clear.  Remember what your English teacher told you about run-on sentences.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should.  Follow the pythonic way, python should be expressive.  If you obfuscate the obvious then you have already failed the most basic principal of python.  for more instructions try `import this`

Comment: After me editing the title, it makes more sense. There do happen situations when in a multiple assignment, an operation needs to be applied to one element but not the others. If the operation is simple, it's natural to try to squeeze it into the one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

This will cast each element from the `split()` with an odd index as `int()` and leave the others as-is:

```
>>> queue_name, tasks_to_lease = (int(v) if n else v for n,v in enumerate('a=3'.split('=')))
>>> queue_name
'a'
>>> tasks_to_lease
3
```

This will cast each element from the `split()` where every character is a number (i.e., won't do negative numbers) to `int()` and leave the others as-is:

```
>>> queue_name, tasks_to_lease = (int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for v in 'a=3'.split('='))
>>> queue_name
'a'
>>> tasks_to_lease
3
```

Answer (score -1):

Not recommended but possible:

```
 s = "foo 10"

a, b = map(lambda x: [lambda _: x, int][x.isdigit()](x) , s.split())

print(type(a), type(b))
print(a, b)

<class 'str'> <class 'int'>
foo 10
```

Comment: I think this needs the console prompts

Comment: @CrazyPython, no it doesn't. Pretty easy to figure that out if you tried it

Comment: @PadriacCunningham Well separate your input and output!

Comment: @CrazyPython. It is separated.

Comment: @PadriacCunningham Well not by text, just an unlabled, no comment space.

Comment: @CrazyPython, based on the four other people that rejected your edit I imagine you are in the minority, if you cannot  distinguish what is code and what is output in this simple example I am a bit baffled.

Comment: @PadriacCunningham, well I can, it's just that it's unclear, and doesn't meet standards

Comment: @CrazyPython, what standards, does http://stackoverflow.com/a/14927518/2141635 meet the *standards*? The community rejected your edit so again you seem to be in the minority

Comment: @PadriacCunningham That was two years ago, now I edit more questions than I ask.

Comment: I didn't notice it and just deleted it, agreeing with the commenters.